# LibGDX - how do i make my Menu switch screens to the game

Tags: java, android, libgdx

The issue I'm encountering right now is when I run the application, The main menu shows up just fine, but then when I click the button to go play the game the Main Menu is still their but the game is running. I know this because I have music in the game. Basically, the main menu doesn't disappear when I run the game. Below is the code that I have.

```
package com.dakotapederson.slingshotsteve;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Game;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.screens.Menu;

public class SlingshotSteve extends Game {

public SpriteBatch batch;
public BitmapFont font;

public void create() {
    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    //Use LibGDX's default Arial font.
    font = new BitmapFont();
    this.setScreen(new Menu(this));
}

public void render() {
    super.render(); //important!
}

public void dispose() {
    batch.dispose();
    font.dispose();
}

}
```

Here is the Main menu screen.

```
public class Menu implements Screen {

final SlingshotSteve game;

OrthographicCamera camera;

public Menu(final SlingshotSteve gam) {
    game = gam;

    camera = new OrthographicCamera();
    camera.setToOrtho(false, 800, 480);
}

@Override
public void render(float delta) {

    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0.2f, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    camera.update();
    game.batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);

    game.batch.begin();
    game.font.draw(game.batch, "Welcome to Slingshot Steve!!! ", 100, 150);
    game.font.draw(game.batch, "Tap anywhere to begin!", 100, 100);
    game.batch.end();

    if (Gdx.input.isTouched()) {
        game.setScreen((Screen) new GameScreen(game));
        dispose();
    }
}
```

And here is the game screen.

```
public class GameScreen implements Screen {
   final SlingshotSteve game;   

   OrthographicCamera camera;
   // Creates our 2D images
   SpriteBatch batch;
   TextureRegion backgroundTexture;
   Texture texture;

   GameScreen(final SlingshotSteve gam) {
        this.game = gam; 

    camera = new OrthographicCamera(1280, 720);

    batch = new SpriteBatch();

    Texture texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("background.jpg"));
    backgroundTexture = new TextureRegion(texture, 0, 0, 500, 500);

    Music mp3Sound = Gdx.audio.newMusic(Gdx.files.internal("rain.mp3"));
    mp3Sound.setLooping(true);
    mp3Sound.play();



}


public void render() {  

      Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

      camera.update();
      batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);

      batch.begin();
      batch.draw(backgroundTexture, 0, 0); 
      batch.end();

}

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {

}

@Override
public void pause() {

}

@Override
public void resume() {

}

@Override
public void dispose() {
       batch.dispose();
       texture.dispose();

}
```

Comment: Reposting your question is frowned upon here on SO. Additionally, you say that your other question was not getting answers, but it now has 2 answers, one of which is accepted. Please read the ["no one answered"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/no-one-answers) FAQ.

Comment: I wasn't talking about my other, I was talking about this one.